# Send the POST variable in ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have the following ajax ,on which im trying to post the `dataString` as a parameter to the php file.
I have tried putting `dataString` inside `xhr.send(dataString);`.But it didnt work out.Is there any way around?

```
dataString = txCryptData;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var params="data="+dataString;
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
 if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
       alert(xhr.responseText);
     }
}
xhr.open('POST', 'tokenize.php', true);
xhr.send();
```

In the php I tried $_POST['params']; to fetch the value posted by the ajax req

Comment: Why don't you send variable params?

Comment: Sorry I tried it.But didnt succeed.I think the problem is in the php? Im using $_POST['params']; there to fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP use this to get the string sent with ajax :

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

And in JS :

```
dataString = txCryptData;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var params="data="+dataString;
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
 if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status==200) {
       alert(xhr.responseText);
     }
}
xhr.open('POST', 'tokenize.php', true);
xhr.send(params);
```

Comment: Ya I changed,this is what I used in php   
 $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
  echo $data;

Answer (score 1):

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    // make sure you respect the same origin policy with this url:
    url: 'youUrl',
    data: { 
        'Joo': 'bar', 
        'ca$libri': 'no$libri' //  $ sign in the parameter name seems unusual, I would avoid it
    },
    success: function(msg){
        alert('Value' + msg);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send(params);
You may have to add these lines to your js snippet